# Prove that $f′′$ has a root in the interval $(0, 1)$.

Tags: calculus

Let $g(x)$ be a function that is twice differentiable for all $x$ and let $f(x) = g(x) −
g(1 − x)$. Prove that $f′′$ has a root in the interval $(0, 1)$.

Comment: Have you tried writing f'' in terms of g?

Comment: Yes, I have it as f"(x)=g"(x)-g"(1-x)

Comment: Okay, is there an x so that g''(x) would equal g''(1-x) no matter what g is?

Comment: @M47145 When I saw the question, I thought "Wow, what a vague, useless title" only to see that it was recently edited. If you're going to add Mathjax to posts that are quite old, why not improve *all* aspects that are lacking? (The question also has nothing to do with differential equations, despite the tag).

Comment: @pjs36 Sure thing! I'll do that. :)

Answer (score 3):

Using the fact that $f$ is twice differentiable and $f''(x)=g''(x)-g''(1-x)$, it is obvious that
$$
f''(0.5)=g''(0.5)-g''(0.5)=0\ .
$$
This shows that $f''$ indeed has a root in $(0,1)$.

Alternatively, if you want to be fancy, you can use the observation that 
$$\begin{align}
f''(1) &= g''(1)-g''(0) \\
&= -\left( g''(0)-g''(1) \right) \\
&=-f''(0)\ ,
\end{align}$$
which shows that $0$ lies between $f''(0)$ and $f''(1)$.

Since $f''$ is the derivative of $f'$, following Mr. Luis Valerin line of reasoning, we can apply the [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) to conclude that there exists some $\xi\in(0,1)$ such that $f''(\xi)=0$. Note that we cannot apply the [Intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) since it is not guaranteed that $f''$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Look that: $f''(0)=g''(0)-g''(1)$ and $f''(1)=g''(1)-g''(0)$ then if $f''(0)=0$ we are done! If not $f''(0)>0$ and therefore $f''(1)<0$. Now, by the Darboux's Theorem there is an $\xi\in (0,1)$ such that $f''(\xi)=0$.

Comment: Darboux... or simply intermediate theorem value if $f''$ is continuous.